# Q-table: rendering several columns from a single field?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a quasar table that displays some information fetched from an API, and I'm trying to define the columns in a way that makes sense. The API, among other things, returns this:

```json
{
  "scan_settings": {
    "group_name": "default_group",
    "profile_id": "Default Scan",
    "scan_occurrence": "Daily",
    "scan_window_duration": 3,
    "scan_window_initial_time": "12:00:00",
    "scan_window_timezone": ""
  }
}
```

I want to display separately `group_name`, `profile_id`, `scan_occurrence`, `scan_window_duration` and `scan_window_initial_time`,

As I understand the [docs](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#defining-the-columns), I could define columns like this:

```js
const columns = [
 {
  name: 'group_name',
  label: 'Qualys scan settings',
  field: row => row?.group_name
 },
 {
  name: 'profile_id',
  label: 'Qualys scan type',
  field: row => row?.profile_id
 },
/* and so on */
]
```

and so each cell would display the value of `scan_settings.group_name` in that column. However, it's as if the table is looking for a property with the same name as the column, and then using that as the argument for the `field` function.

This would work with a plain `q-table` but I'm using the `body` slot, too, to change display depending on the type of info it's been shown (checkboxes for booleans and so forth)

This is how the `body` slot looks like (omitting some stuff for brevity):

```
 <template #body="props">
      <q-tr :props="props">
        <q-td
          v-for="col in props.cols"
          :key="col.name"
          :props="props"
          class="table-cell"
        >
          <span v-if="dateColumns.includes(col.name)">
            {{ parseISODateStringToLocale(props.row[col.name]) }}
          </span>
          <!-- omitted for brevity -->
          <span v-else>
            {{ props.row[col.name] }}
          </span>
        </q-td>
      </q-tr>
    </template>
```

Notice how the template looks for the value - that is the problem, that's what introduces this behaviour. But I don't know what would be the best way to put that value inside of the template instead. What can I do?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/wvXRoWZ It's working fine for me

Comment: Thank you! Some fiddling with your codepen has shown me what the problem is. I'm not sure what the best solution would be, though. I will edit the post to provide some more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `body` slot then fields you can't use directly.

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/wvXRoWZ